# Error attempting to open image with matplotlib.image

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

The following code does not work for me:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
im = mpimg.imread('./dat/grey.jpg')
```

I have ensured that the `grey.jpg` exists, and I have PIL installed from [here](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Here's the error i'm getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1278, in imread
    im = pilread(fname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1256, in pilread
    with Image.open(fname) as image:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __exit__
```

any ideas on what's going on here? I'm thinking it could be a dependency issue. I have Python 2.7 32bit also

Comment: It looks like Matplotlib is assume PIL/pillow provides open as a context manager and you have a version of PIL that does not.  I suggest switching to pillow (which is a drop-in replacement that is pip installable and is maintained).

Answer (score -2):

Just install pillow, using `conda` that would be:

```
conda install pillow
```